# HTML to JSON with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a specific HTML structure into JSON using BeautifulSoup using the following code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    html = """<h1>Heading</h1>
<h1>More heading</h1>
<p>test</p>
<h2>Section</h2>
<p>a.b.c</p>
<h3>Prio</h3>
<p>Medium</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Description 1</p>
<p>Description 2</p>
<h3>Foo</h3>
<p>Foo 1</p>
<p>Foo 2</p>
<h3>Bar</h3>
<p>Bar 1</p>
<p>Bar 2</p>
<p>Bar 3</p>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<p>Baz 1</p>
<h2>Section</h2>
<h3>Prio</h3>
<p>High</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Description 3</p>
<p>Description 4</p>
<h3>Foo</h3>
<p>Foo 3</p>
<h2>Section</h2>
<h3>Prio</h3>
<p>Low</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Description 5</p>
<p>Description 6</p>
<h3>Foo</h3>
<p>Foo 4</p>
<p>Foo 5</p>
<h3>Bar</h3>
<p>Bar 4</p>
<p>Bar 5</p>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<p>Baz 2</p>
<h2>Section</h2>
<h3>Prio</h3>
<p>Medium</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Description 7</p>
<h3>Foo</h3>
<p>Foo 6</p>
<h3>Bar</h3>
<p>Bar 6</p>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<p>Baz 3</p>"""
    
    json = {}
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    json['Category'] = soup.find('h1').string
        
    for section in soup.find_all('h2'):
        p = ''
        content = {}
        for sibling in section.next_siblings:
            if sibling.name == 'h3':
                prev_section = sibling.find_previous_sibling('h3')
                if prev_section:
                    if not prev_section.text == 'Baz' and not prev_section.text == 'Bar':
                        content[prev_section.text] = p
                p = ''
            if sibling.name == 'p':
                if not p:
                    p = sibling.text
                else:
                    p = p + '\n' + sibling.text
            elif sibling.name == 'h2':
                data.append(content)
                content = {}
                p = ''
    json['Data'] = data
    print(json)
```

The issue I'm having is that it's not a tree structure, but only siblings. My expected result would be this:

```
{'Category': 'Heading', 'Data': [{'Prio': 'Medium', 'Description': 'Description 1\nDescription 2', 'Foo': 'Foo 1\nFoo 2'}, {'Prio': 'High', 'Description': 'Description 3\nDescription 4', 'Foo': 'Foo 4\nFoo 5'}, {'Prio': 'Low', 'Description': 'Description 5\nDescription 6', 'Foo': 'Foo 4\nFoo 5'}, {'Prio': 'Medium', 'Description': 'Description 7', 'Foo': 'Foo 6'}]}
```

However, the above code gets me this:

```
{'Category': 'Heading', 'Data': [{'Prio': 'Medium', 'Description': 'Description 1\nDescription 2', 'Foo': 'Foo 1\nFoo 2'}, {'Prio': 'High', 'Description': 'Description 3\nDescription 4'}, {'Foo': 'Foo 4\nFoo 5', 'Prio': 'Low', 'Description': 'Description 5\nDescription 6'}, {'Prio': 'High', 'Description': 'Description 3\nDescription 4'}, {'Foo': 'Foo 4\nFoo 5', 'Prio': 'Low', 'Description': 'Description 5\nDescription 6'}, {'Foo': 'Foo 4\nFoo 5', 'Prio': 'Low', 'Description': 'Description 5\nDescription 6'}]}
```

So, basically, the gist would be to getting the first h2, parsing everything that comes after it, while sectioning it, according to the h3 values, until the next h2 value is found. I just do not really see how to do this in BeautifulSoup.
Any pointer into the right direction appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You want a way to keep count the sections (via `h2`). You want a loop that handles a section at time (via sibling filtering and if `tag.name == h2` in order to escape loop as can't reference siblings from self at that point) and a way to track if you are at an `h3` and need to add to a key and value to the current dictionary. If the key is already present you need to add paragraphs to the value for that key. You also want to filter out `bar` and `baz` (via `:not` `:contains`) and the `h2 + p`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
html = """your html"""
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
total_sections = len(soup.select('h2'))
result = {}
result['Category'] = soup.select_one('h1').text
data = []

 for i in range(1, total_sections + 1): 
    temp = {}

    for j in soup.select(f'h2:nth-of-type({i}) ~ *:not(h2 + p, :contains("Bar"), :contains("Baz"), h2:nth-of-type({i + 1}), h2:nth-of-type({i + 1}) ~ *)'):
        if j.name == 'h2':
            break
        item = j.next_sibling.strip()

        if j.name == 'h3':  
            flag = j.text
            temp[flag] = item
        else:
            temp[flag] += ' ' + j.text
    data.append(temp)
result['Data'] = data
print(result)
```

As is, the `elif` isn't really needed and could be replaced with:

```
else:
    temp[flag] += ' ' + j.text
```